# Accessing Objects From A Worker Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, object, mfc, statusbar

I have a worker thread and I need to increment the progress bar from a CMFCStatusBar pane. It works fine in release mode however in debug mode it trips a breakpoint.

Problem is the unsafe accessing of the status bar object from within a thread. wincore.cpp states from the breakpoint that objects should be accessed using handles.

How would you go about accessing the CMFCStatusBar a member of CFrameWindowEx using handles?

Comment: Look at PostMessage(), SendMessage().  Add a custom message handler to your progress bar and post/send such a message from the work thread to the handle of the progressBar.

Answer (score 1):

See FAQs 11 and 12 here:

http://vcfaq.mvps.org/mfc/index.htm

This shows an example of how to use the technique suggested above by Martin James.